# sql server remote access machine ip

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanna learn remote machine's ip adressess which accessed my sql server. someone at my job(in local network) find my database password and making row updates. how could I find the access person's ip?

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server you can try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCurrentIP] ()
RETURNS varchar(280)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IP_Address varchar(280);

    SELECT @IP_Address = client_net_address
    FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
    WHERE Session_id = @@SPID;

    Return @IP_Address;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a trigger to the table that adds the server variables like host name to a separate table.  See trigger on update. Also select host_name.